# Alfresco share worflow form validation

Tags: alfresco-share

I have been trying to validate my alfresco share workflow form for several days without success. This is what i have done.

1. Configured my workflow in the share-config-custom.xml located in %TOMCAT_HOME%tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\web-extension
2. set my contraint handler as follows.

   ```
                   <constraint-handlers>
                       <constraint type="MANDATORY"
                           validation-handler="Alfresco.forms.validation.examplestaffnumber"
                           event="keyup" />
                   </constraint-handlers>
               </field>
   ```

   This field i have set to mandatory
   < label-id="Staff Number" id="leave:staffnumber" mandatory="true">
3. I have created the contraint hanlder javascript and placed it at %ALFRESCO_HOME%\tomcat\webapps\share\js folder. This is both js and min.js
4. Finaly added the js in form.get.head.ftl located at %ALFRESCO_HOME%tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\form 
   folder like this
   <@script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/js/examplevalidation.js">

When I select my worflow form and key values in the staff number form nothing happens. I have checked in the firebug but there is no any call to the js. 
Where could i have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not added dependencies for your java script. To do that add below code in your share-config-custom.xml located in %ALFRESCO_HOME%tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\web-extension

```
<config>
    <forms>
        <dependencies>
            <js src="/js/examplevalidation.js" />
        </dependencies>
    </forms>
</config>
```

And your constrains handler should be like

```
<field id="leave:staffnumber" label-id="Staff Number" mandatory="true">
    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textfield.ftl" />
        <constraint-handlers>
            <constraint type="MANDATORY" validation-handler="Alfresco.forms.validation.examplestaffnumber" event="blur"/>
        </constraint-handlers>
</field>
```

And function in your js should be like this:

```
Alfresco.forms.validation.examplestaffnumber = function examplestaffnumber(
            field, args, event, form, silent, message) {
    // your code with return statement
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks @NaMaN this has worked. You have really saved me a big pain. wish i can get your email